# edit kendoTemplate on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using kendoTemplate to show the images on page.
Here is code for it:

```
   <div id="listView" class="k-listview" style="text-align:left"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="product">
        <img id='base64image' style='display:block; width:300px;height:300px; src='data:image/jpeg;base64,#:fileData#' /></a>
        <div class="edit-buttons">
          <center> 
              <span class="k-label">&nbsp; #:fileDesc# </span><br>
              <a id="deleteAccess" class="k-button k-delete-button">Delete<span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a>
             </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</script> </div>
```

Here is my code for creating kendoListView:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {

          var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "URL", type: "get",
                    }
                },
            });

            var listview = $("#listView").kendoListView({
                remove: { //Remove Code }
                    }
                    else {
                        var deleteurl = //SomeURL
                        $.ajax({
                            url: deleteurl,
                            data: { XYZ },
                            success:  { //Success Code  },
                            error: {//ErrorCode }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
            }).data("kendoListView");
```

In my template I have "deleteAccess" button. I want to make it display on  rolebase. I know that I can hide by `document.getElementById('deleteAccess').style.display= "none";`

When I write the line (hide code) in `document.ready()` function (Yes, after rolebase condition check) it gives me an error saying "can not add style property of undefined". I am not able to figure out where I need to write to code to get desired output.

Expected output: For user who do not have access should not able to see "Delete" Button.

Thank You

Comment: What is *rolebase*? A property in your data ? What type ? What values it has ?

Comment: maybe use dataBound event so you know listview has been rendered: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listview#events-dataBound